# Algorithm for finding numbers that sum up to a certain integer

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I am looking to create an algorithm that produces all of the numbers that sum to a number under certain rules.

1. There should be exactly two **different** natural numbers that are used for the summation. (For our purpose, 4 is a different number than 2 even though it can be expressed as 2+2)
2. Every number must appear at least twice.
3. No other numbers can be used

**End of question** - The following section is providing examples and clarifications.

So if I was looking for the numbers that satisfy the rules for the number **12**, I would have:

```
2+2+4+4 // Two 2's and two 4's
2+2+2+3+3 // Three 2's and two 3's
5*2+2*1 //Five 2's and two 1's
4*2+4*1 //Four 2's and four 1's
3*2+6*1 // Three 2's and six 1's
2*2+8*1 //Two 2's and eight 1's
2*4+4*1 //Two 4's and four 1's
```

These will not satisfy the rules:

```
4+3+3+2 // Fails rules 1 and 2
3+3+6 //Fails rule 2
1+1+2+2+3+3 //Fails rule 1
1+1+2+2 //doesn't add up to 12
```

**What kind of strategies can I adopt, to avoid having to "brute-force" numbers until I find a pattern that fits?**

For instance:

- if the sum of both numbers*2>goal ---> they get automatically disqualified
- if my goal is even, and I have an odd number of odd components---->they get automatically disqualified

What other things I may want to consider as I create this algorithm?

Comment: What's wrong with $5+5+1+1=12$?

Comment: @lulu Nothing, it's the 3rd example

Comment: Well, a usual first step is to list the answer for small $n$.  Then look at [OEIS](https://oeis.org) to see if it matches a recognized sequence.  My first guess is that it's messy.  Pick if $n$ is your target, pick $m<n$ and count the relevant partitions for which $m$ is the larger number.  That means look at all multiples $km≤n-2$.  then you have to look at all possible factorings of $n-km$ where at least one factor is $<m$.  That's why I expect it is messy.

Comment: That's a cool starting point!

Comment: For your count, the third example is described as $2+2+2+2+2+1+1$ (you write "five $2's$ and two $1's$").  Are you saying that this is the same as $5+5+1+1$ because both can be written as $5\times 2 +2\times 1$?

Comment: Yes! Both have 2 different numbers that appear at least twice.

Comment: So, those are two different partitions, right?  I mean, you do distinguish between $2+2+2+2+1+1+1+1$ and $4+4+1+1+1+1$,  I'm just trying to clarify the count.  What do you think the count is for $12$?

Comment: oh oh, I see. Yeah, they should be counted twice.Thanks for the clarifying question

Comment: Fine, so like I say, work out the answer for $n=1,2,\cdots 12$ or so and see if OEIS recognizes it.  Well, I guess $6=2+2+1+1$ is the first meaningful example, so start there.

Comment: Will do. I'll give it a try